# Why is my code for Project Euler #12 so slow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, solver

```
def trisum():
    divs = 1
    great = 1
    n = 1
    while divs < 500:
        divs = 1
        n += 1
        tri = sum(i for i in range(1,n+1))
        #divisors = [tri]
        for x in range(1,tri):
            if tri%x == 0:
                #divisors.append(x)
                divs += 1
            else:
                pass
        if divs > great:
            great = tri
            print(great)
        #grVal = sorted(divisors, reverse=True)        
        #print("{}: {}".format(divs,tri))
    print(great)

trisum()
s = input("")
```

This is my code to solve the triangle value for which over 500 divisors can be found, it works for smaller numbers, but for 500 it takes really long, I haven't been able to get an answer either. I'm 90% my code works for every number of divisors and I went from a list to just assigning a variable to the greatest triangle sum.

Why is my code still so slow? Any help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `tri = n*(n+1)/2`. You don't actually have to generate a list of `n` numbers and then add them up.

Comment: Project Euler puzzles are designed to reward thinking deeply about the mathematics of the problem. They are very rewarding, but I highly recommend a brief bit of research on some basic number theory to help you along - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function is a good place to start!

Comment: because you're using python. use c

Comment: I just learnt Java, and wrote the same code, it's still taking too long, or the code I wrote is completely incorrect, are Java and C synonymous in speed or? @willywonka_dailyblah

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah Switching from Python to C will only speed things up by a factor.  To get to a solution to a Project Euler problem, you need to speed things up by a order of magnitude (or more) over the obvious brute force solution (by thinking deeply about the mathematics behind the problem).  At that point, a factor for the execution time will be irrelevant, and you can stick with Python.

Comment: @Teepeemm yep, I was joking. (in hindsight I shoulda added :) )

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reduce the computing of the sum by simply adding

```
i = 1
tri = i
while divisors < 100:
    tri += i
    # do something
    i += 1
```

Also,  don't go up to tri when finding divisors, go up to

```
int(tri / 2)
```

as the largest number which can evenly divide any number is half of the number. [Hope this helps, I can't test because I'm using my phone]

Comment: Pretty sure you only have to go up to `math.sqrt(tri)`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the #do something part of your psudo code please?

Comment: @mVChr think 36, for **all** divisors, ex 18 is a divisor.

Comment: @SuperNova you can get 18 though when you're on 2 of the loop by dividing the triangle number by it. Saves you from going through a lot of loop iterations on the larger numbers.

Comment: @mVChr j was trying to keep It simple, if you could put the code in the comments, we'd appreciate it, as I'm on my phone, it'd be somethjng like

Comment: If tri % n == 0: divisors += 2

Comment: @MVChar Sqrt(n) is checking for primality I do believe